# Failing to load all items of an [UIButton] array for Pinterest-like iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, pinterest

My objective is to create a Pinterest-like iOS app. I use a collection view and then, programatically I add a stack view. I create the buttons and it's respective images within a function and then I return all the UIButtons in an array of [UIButtons]. I store the value of that function in a variable called buttonsArray, and then I use it in the respective Collection View data source and delegate methods. I also use PinterestLayout created by RayWenderlich. Everything works as expected except for the fact that instead of loading all buttons, it only loads the first two. The function where I add the items goes as follows:

```
func createArrayButtons() -> [UIButton]{

    var items:[UIButton] = []

    let item1 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:346,height:275))
    item1.setImage(UIImage(named: "1"), for: .normal)
    item1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editButtonTapped), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    item1.tag = 1
    items.append(item1)

    let item2 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:346,height:275))
    item2.setImage(UIImage(named: "2"), for: .normal)
    item2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editButtonTapped), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    item2.tag = 2
    items.append(item2)

    let item3 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:346,height:275))
    item3.setImage(UIImage(named: "3"), for: .normal)
    item3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editButtonTapped), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    item3.tag = 3
    items.append(item3)

    let item4 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:346,height:275))
    item4.setImage(UIImage(named: "4"), for: .normal)
    item4.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editButtonTapped), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    item4.tag = 4
    items.append(item4)

    let item5 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:346,height:275))
    item5.setImage(UIImage(named: "5"), for: .normal)
    item5.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editButtonTapped), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    item5.tag = 5
    items.append(item5)

    let item6 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:346,height:275))
    item6.setImage(UIImage(named: "6"), for: .normal)
    item6.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editButtonTapped), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    item6.tag = 6
    items.append(item6)

    let item7 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:346,height:275))
    item7.setImage(UIImage(named: "7"), for: .normal)
    item7.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editButtonTapped), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    item7.tag = 7
    items.append(item7)

    return items

}
```

I give each one a respective tag and a respective image from the assets folder, then return it as an array.

I calculate the collectionViewDataSource as follows

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let buttonsArray = createArrayButtons()
    return buttonsArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    let buttonsArray = createArrayButtons()

    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: buttonsArray)
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
    stackView.alignment = .fill
    stackView.spacing = 5
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    cell.addSubview(stackView)





    return cell
}
```

And I calculate the height of each item as follows:

```
extension ViewController: PinterestLayoutDelegate {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let buttonArray = createArrayButtons()

    let button = buttonArray[indexPath.item]

    let height = button.imageView?.image?.size.height

    return height!
}
```

}

As you can see, the app only shows the first two images of the createButtonsArray() variable stored in each dataSource Method

[image]

[image]

[image]

Every image that i store as the returning value of createArrayButtons is different, however it only loads up two. How could I solve this?

If it's of any help, my project can be found in the following link:

https://github.com/francisc112/PinterestTutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update code at `cellForItemAt indexPath` as you are loading the whole button array for each cell.

```
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [buttonsArray[indexPath.row]])
```

Comment: @FranciscoRuiz, Welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps below to get the required result,

**1 -** In storyboard, drag a `UIStackView` in collectionCell and set constraints to zero from all sides. Set distribution and spacing as shown in the image[image]

**2 -** Update `ButtonCollectionViewCell` as below

```
class ButtonCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var button:UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var stackView: UIStackView!

}
```

**3 -** Open storyboard again and make a connection with the stackView like in the image [image]

**4 -** Change `viewDidLoad` to this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.delegate = self

    let collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = collectionViewLayout

    collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

**5 -** Conform `ViewController` to this

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2 - 20, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
    }
}
```

**6 -** Update `cellForItemAt` with this

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ButtonCollectionViewCell

        for (_, view) in cell.stackView.arrangedSubviews.enumerated() {
            cell.stackView.removeArrangedSubview(view)
        }
        let buttonsArray = createArrayButtons()
        buttonsArray.forEach { button in
            cell.stackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
        }
        cell.stackView.layoutIfNeeded()
        cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
        return cell
    }
```

Now you should be able to see the proper results.